# Canvas does not draw smooth lines

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, antialiasing

I am not able to get anitialiazed lines when doing freehand drawing in javafx canvas.
Following is the code ...

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class Test2 extends Application {
  GraphicsContext gc;

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  private class MouseDragged implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
      public void handle( MouseEvent e ) {
        gc.lineTo( e.getX(), e.getY() );
        gc.stroke();
      }
  }

  private class MousePressed implements EventHandler<MouseEvent> {
      public void handle( MouseEvent e ) {
        gc.moveTo( e.getX(), e.getY() );
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);
    canvas.setOnMouseDragged( new MouseDragged() );
    canvas.setOnMousePressed( new MousePressed() );

    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setLineCap( StrokeLineCap.ROUND );
    gc.setLineJoin( StrokeLineJoin.ROUND );
    gc.setLineWidth( 0.1 );

    Group root = new Group(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setTitle("Test2");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
}
```

While if I create a swing app I can provide rendering hints to smoothen it out ...

```
g2.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
```

How do I provide rendering hits to the graphics context in canvas?

Comment: Log a feature request against the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com)

Comment: The old JavaFX issue tracker link is dead.  Feature requests can be logged against http://bugreport.java.com (I think), though you would probably have better luck getting the feature request implemented if you discussed in on [the openjfx-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/mailman/listinfo/openjfx-dev) first before logging it.

Comment: Note that the actual issue here might be drawing over the same points multiple times, which makes the antialiased lines appear aliased.  See related question: [How to apply antialiasing to javafx methods like GraphicsContext.fillArc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148521/how-to-apply-antialiasing-to-javafx-methods-like-graphicscontext-fillarc)

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this effect to your `GraphicsContext`:

```
BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur();
blur.setWidth(1);
blur.setHeight(1);
blur.setIterations(1);
gc.setEffect(blur);
```

So (as an example) your `start` method would now look like this:

```
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);
    canvas.setOnMouseDragged( new MouseDragged() );
    canvas.setOnMousePressed( new MousePressed() );

    gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    gc.setLineCap( StrokeLineCap.ROUND );
    gc.setLineJoin( StrokeLineJoin.ROUND );
    gc.setLineWidth( 1 );

    BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur();
    blur.setWidth(1);
    blur.setHeight(1);
    blur.setIterations(1);
    gc.setEffect(blur);

    Group root = new Group(canvas);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setTitle("Test2");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
```

It's not exactly perfect... but the best thing I've found so far.

Comment: Nice alternative. But for this purpose I think i'll stick with swing for a while. There are few things that i cant do without the flexibility of bufferedimage.