# JavaFX slow performance on canvas when drawing freestyle with pen

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I was trying out the code here for making a JavaFX app which allows my stylus pen to draw on a canvas: [Canvas does not draw smooth lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816558/canvas-does-not-draw-smooth-lines)

The performance is extremely painful when trying to draw on a canvas. It will freeze for half a second, and then start drawing. Only after it starts drawing is it fine. Beforehand though when you first press down with the mouse/pen, the delay is pretty brutal and makes it unusable.

Here is the code I used:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.effect.BoxBlur;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineCap;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeLineJoin;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    private GraphicsContext gc;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500, 500);
        canvas.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            gc.lineTo(e.getX(), e.getY());
            gc.stroke();
        });
        canvas.setOnMousePressed(e -> gc.moveTo(e.getX(), e.getY()));

        gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
        gc.setLineJoin(StrokeLineJoin.ROUND);
        gc.setLineWidth(1);

        BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur();
        blur.setWidth(1);
        blur.setHeight(1);
        blur.setIterations(1);
        gc.setEffect(blur);

        Group root = new Group(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to fix the performance issue? My desktop computer is pretty solid and can run high-end games, so its not the performance on my computer.

NOTE: I should also say that the delay that occurs when you first press the mouse on the canvas is bad enough to cause mouse clicks to drop.

EDIT: To confirm it wasnt the OnMousePressed, I commented it out and it did not help.

Comment: I'm not experiencing any performance problem with your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is user error (myself) and not a valid question anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my driver was conflicting somehow with Java, which means JavaFX is fine. After getting help from the tablet company and some fixes, this doesn't happen with the latest drivers.