# How to draw a curve consisting of multiple line segments in a non-jagged way

Tags: canvas, javafx, bezier

I am trying to write a program that puts incoming USB data onto a line graph. The way I have done this is by drawing onto the canvas a bunch of straight lines connecting all the data points. The problem is that the resulting line is not smooth, as you can see below:

[image: Jagged Line]

I tried using Graphics Context's `lineTo(x, y)` method but that just made it worse. I also tried changing the Line Cap and Line Join parameters but that didn't help much.

Is there a better way to play "Connect the Dots" with JavaFX Graphics Context? Perhaps with bezier curves? If there is, then please let me know.

Comment: Have you considered using the built in LineChart?
 https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/chart/LineChart.html

Comment: I don't think Canvas includes native support for antialiasing lines (see duplicate question).  Antialiasing is supported if you draw the lines on a scene graph instead of on a canvas, so perhaps you can try that.

Comment: Hmm, this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34148521/how-to-apply-antialiasing-to-javafx-methods-like-graphicscontext-fillarc) actually indicates that antialiasing does occur when drawing shape primitives such as lines to a canvas.

Comment: So perhaps if you use a [bezier curve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#bezierCurveTo-double-double-double-double-double-double-) as you originally speculated, you may end up with a better outcome.  You could try the algorithm referenced here to fit curves to points: http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/curve-fitting-and-styling-areachart/ (that is scene graph based, so you would need to adjust it for your canvas based solution).

Comment: @jewelsea Perhaps I am mistaken, but I don't think this is an issue with GC not antialiasing. The curve is made up of a bunch of tiny lines that I drew, and as far as those lines "know", they are not connected.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, I removed the duplicate tag.  You might want to update the title to something more descriptive (e.g. How to draw a curve consisting of multiple line segments in a non-jagged way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with the simplest solution to the problem, which is just to use a BoxBlur effect:

```
BoxBlur blur = new BoxBlur();
blur.setWidth(2);
blur.setHeight(2);
blur.setIterations(1);

gc.setEffect(blur);

 ...

//Don't forget to remove the effect before clearing
gc.setEffect(null);
gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

It's not an exact solution, but it works just fine for my purposes.